# Howto prevent Dolphin from triggering /foo/nfs-share.automount

Tags: systemd, nfs, automounting, dolphin

since i switched to auto-suspend there's an unwanted delay when reactivating due to the lost nfs-mounts (debian 11)

I created some auto(u)mount (systemd) which is working fine... as long as dolphin is closed.
Dolphin remounts immediately.
I don't have baloo installed, also I have no preview activated in dolphin.

How can I change this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.